# invalidateOptionsMenu() does not work with AppCompatActivity

Tags: android, android-menu, android-appcompat

I switched my `Activity` to a `AppCompatActivity` and now calling `invalidateOptionsMenu()` in `onOptionsItemSelected()` no longer updates the Menu items as they did before. `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` is not called.

I added the following dependency

```
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1"
```

And updated my `Activity` to a `AppCompatActivity` (note only the first call to `invalidateOptionsMenu()` in `onResume()` works, the the other two do not):

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private boolean isStopSaved;

    // ...

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if (/* Check DB if star should be set */) {
            isStopSaved = true;
        } else {
            isStopSaved = false;
        }
        invalidateOptionsMenu(); // This updates the menu as expected
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // ...

        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_schedule, menu);   
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_starred_add:
            isStopSaved = true;
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // Does not update menu
            break;

        case R.id.menu_starred_remove:
            isStopSaved = false;
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // Does not update menu
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

**Edit:** My device is running Android M Preview 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested using the latest support library, and it is working fine again.

```
com.android.support:appcompat-v7::23.0.1
```

Answer (score 15):

You should call [`supportInvalidateOptionsMenu()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html#supportInvalidateOptionsMenu()), which is meant to work with the support libraries.

Comment: From the `appcompat-v7` source `invalidateOptionsMenu()` and `supportInvalidateOptionsMenu()` do the same thing: https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/v7/appcompat/src/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.java#L186

Comment: I see - it was not like so when we had only ActionBarActivity.

Comment: Yea, I think something changed when `ActionBarActivity` became deprecated in favour of `AppCompatAcitivity`. Perhaps it is a bug with the `appcompat-v7` library or Android M.

Answer (score 0):

change your onOptionsItemSelected like below:

```
switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.menu_starred_add:
        isStopSaved = false;
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
        break;

    case R.id.menu_starred_remove:
        isStopSaved = true;
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
        break;
}
```

Comment: The logic is okay since it worked fine with `Activity`. The problem is that `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` is not being called.